# Windows Phone 8.1 - Horizontally scrollable StackPanel on a ListView

Tags: listview, scroll, windows-phone-8.1, stackpanel

I want to put a horizontally scrollable StackPanel with items in it, on a vertical scrollable ListView. The parent is the ListView and it's items contain a StackPanel.

**Problem:**
The ListView scrolls fine vertically. But the horizontal StackPanels won't scroll horizontally on the ListView. Why not? Even when they are in a ScrollView.

How can I make a horizontal StackPanel to horizontally scroll on a vertical ListView?

[image: Here is an image illustrating it]

**Code Example:**

```
<Grid x:Name="MainFragment" Background="White">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,5">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="#FF94CF6C">
                    <StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Badges:" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="18">
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Ok I put a code example.

Comment: Stackpael doest not provide scrolling. I think you are looking for the "FlipView" control, but not sure if it going to work inside a ListView...